# How to integrate php generated css in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme which injects dynamically with php created css code into the html head section of my wordpress site.

The actual css-code is defined as a string variable with the different css-style information sequentially being appended to this variable. This whole thing is nested within a function which is loaded into the head section via the `wp_head` hook looking like:

```
function dynamic_css() {
$header_options = get_option( 'header_opt' );

/*... more code here ...*/

$css = '<style>';
$css .= '.logo {
    max-width:'. $header_options['logo_width'] .'px;
}';

$css .= '.header-center > .center-max-width {
    height:'. $header_options['center_height'] .'px;
}';

/*... more code here ...*/

$css .= '</style>';

echo '' . $css;

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'dynamic_css' );
```

I'd rather have this dynamic css file loaded as extra stylesheet than having inline code inside my head section.
With help of two stackoverflow discussions regarding dynamic css([this][1] and [this][2]) I tried to alter the existing script so that I can load it as css stylesheet via `wp_enqueue_style` hook in my `functions.php`. The `dynamic_css.php` looks as follows:

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

function dynamic_css() {
$header_options = get_option( 'header_opt' );

/*... more code here ...*/

$css = '.logo {
    max-width:'. $header_options['logo_width'] .'px;
}';

$css .= '.header-center > .center-max-width {
    height:'. $header_options['center_height'] .'px;
}';

/*... more code here ...*/

echo $css;

}

dynamic_css();
```

and the hook in the `functions.php`:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dynamic_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dynamic_css.php');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles');
```

Unfortunately this does not work and I don't know why. There's no error message and in the source.html the file is correctly listed.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dynamic_style-css' href='...website_url.../dynamic_css.php?ver=...' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

However the css styling information is not loaded and applied to the site. To me it seems that the php file is not executed. I don't understand why concatinating the styling information to one variable and directly echoing this variable to the html head section works, but loading it as as stylesheet doesn't.

Thanks for any hint and help!

The
[1]: [Dynamic CSS with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548571/dynamic-css-with-php)
[2]: [How can I use php to generate css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474340/how-can-i-use-php-to-generate-css)

Comment: is there any error in the console??

Comment: judging by the log there seems to be an issue with the `get_option` function: `PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_option()`. In the existing script this `get_option()` is callable without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this maybe:

```
function dynamic_css() {
    $header_options = get_option( 'header_opt' );

    /*... more code here ...*/

    $css = '.logo {
        max-width:'. $header_options['logo_width'] .'px;
    }';

    $css .= '.header-center > .center-max-width {
        height:'. $header_options['center_height'] .'px;
    }';

    /*... more code here ...*/

    $css_file_path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/dynamic.css';
    
    // Write the dynamic CSS to the file, replacing existing content
    file_put_contents($css_file_path, $css);
}
```

And then:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    dynamic_css();
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dynamic_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dynamic.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).